# Why does Next.js require pages to be nested in the pages folder and why can't 'index' be used instead of 'page' for indexes?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So, today I had my first interaction with nextjs, and it was a bit weird, since in react I had to do more complex stuff, to achieve routing.
I've created an nextjs app (last version) with command:
`npx create-next-app@latest --typescript`
At the installation, I've choosed to use /app directory, and no /src one (it says that is experimental, but someone suggested it).

I've created, inside the app folder, a new folder named pages, then test and inside test folder, a page.tsx.
(/app/pages/test/page.tsx)

Why do I have to go to url/pages/test, instead of url/test?

Also, why I cannot use index instead of page, for indexes?

I've tried to move the /pages/ outside of /app folder, but unfortunately, didn't work.
Also, tried to create (inside /app) the name of the page I want (test.tsx) thinking it might work... but didn't.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the app directory? https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/fundamentals Any folder inside `/app` will be treated as a route segment. Including `pages/`. It seems like you’re confusing the new app directory (in beta mode) vs the currently supported pages directory. If you want to use `ROOT_URL/test` then you should have the file at `/app/test/page.js`

Comment: I was reading the docs for nextjs 13, stable version.. didn't see that there is a beta docs here. I'm going to check it out and come back with an answer.

Comment: @Terry thank you. I was confused that I was reading the stable version of the docs, now it makes sense.